# debugging python single stepping within a line (micro-stepping?)

Tags: python, debugging

The python debugger, pdb, as far as I can tell steps a line at a time.

Python is one of those languages that people tend to write long one-line expressions in.

Is there some way in a debugger like pdb to "microstep" *within* a line of code?  As in, is there a way to single step after each part of an expression is complete before handing the value to the next part of the expression and being able to examine what is being returned at each point?

I realize if the file could be edited (which is not always possible or practical), then such a line could be broken up by inserting newlines or by adding intermediate values, but it's not always possible to edit a file, especially if you're stepping into a library.

Comment: "Python is one of those languages that people tend to write long one-line expressions in."[citation needed]. While its possible, and clever, its usually not done because long chained lines can become less readable.

Comment: @MichaelGrant - have you tried the 'step' (s) instruction in the debugger?

Comment: @mata: Try stepping through, e.g., `return 2*i**2 + 3*i +4`. There are two steps: one to compute the entire expression, and one to return the value. There's no intermediate step to compute, e.g., `3*i`. I think that's what he's asking for.

Comment: @mata - 'step' (s) steps a line at a time.  If the line has a for loop it steps each iteration of the loop.  But this still isn't fine grained enough some times.

Comment: @abarnert - I'm not talking about stopping at each term in a polynomial.  But if you had a line like x = f1().f2(f3()).f4(), or say x=f1()+f2().  However in the case of a function you could always step into these function and then use the 'r' command.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: "fluent-style" code chaining a bunch of method calls together is very rare in Python, except in a handful of specific application areas (object databases, bindings for things like COM and Apple Events, etc.). In fact, the stdlib is specifically designed to avoid it (e.g., `append` and `sort` return `None`, not `self`). And even if those examples _were_ common, there's nothing to step into except the function calls, which you can already do. So… can you come up with a better example of something you can't step through, but would like to?

Answer (score 0):

First, in my experience, people *don't* write long one-line expressions in Python… Of course you can, but PEP 8 discourages it, and the tutorial, stdlib, and other sample code you usually learn from doesn't look like that.

However, people *do* write very *complex* expressions. In particular, they use things like comprehensions and iterators.

Anyway, either way, it's somewhat ambiguous what the subexpressions of such a thing are, so it's not clear what it should meant to step into them.

Let's take a trivial example:

```
x = [i*2 for i in range(3)]
```

Clearly, `range(3)` is a subexpression. But what else? Is `i*2` a subexpression? Or three of them?

Under the covers, what this actually looks like is:

```
x = _hidden_func(range(3))
```

And that hidden function (which is actually named something like `<listcomp-123912576>`, not `_hidden_func`) was built directly out of bytecode at compile time, and doesn't map to any actual valid Python code. It's roughly like this:

```
def _hidden_func(iterable):
    result = []
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        try:
            i = next(iterator)
            result.append(i*2)
        except StopIteration:
            return result
```

… but it uses fast list-building and `next`-with-`StopIteration`-handling bytecodes that don't map to anything you could actually write.

So, in order to see the `i*2` at all, you'd need to step into a function that has no source code, and can't even be decompiled into source code on the fly.

In fact, `pdb` can already do this… but it can't show you anything interesting.

There are obviously a variety of things you *could* do with this code. And you could pick one of those things and write custom code that does it. [This visualizer](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) shows one possibility.

The same visualizer treats a long but simple expression, like `x = 2 * i**2 + 3 * i + 4`, as a single step, but you could obviously handle that by, e.g., stepping through the bytecodes and decompiling each "interesting" bytecode.

But again, you'd have to decide what counts as "interesting", and write the appropriate code. `i**2` is probably interested, but what about `i`? Do you care whether it's doing a local, closure, or global lookup to get it, or what that lookup finds, or do you just want to skip it?

Comment: Yes, hmm, as I said in comment above I was not thinking about stepping through terms of a polynomial.  My question was really on the level of was there some different step command I wasn't aware of or was there a better python debugger.Clearly if you could step to the point of `x = 2 * i**2 + 3` and then evaluate the parts by copy/paste.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Well, you could just as easily evaluate the parts of `x = f1().f2(f3()).f4()` by copy/paste. But you really don't have to; you can already step into functions, and there's nothing else in that expression worth stepping into.

Comment: You could evaluate those functions like you say but if they do something like change the state of something internally or cause some other side effect, you have changed the state of things and potentially invalidated your debugging.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Sure, and `i**2` could just as easily change the state of something internally. By convention, in Python, operators and functions that mutate the value return `None`, not `self` or some other result of the computation. So, you can expect that `2 * i**2 + 3` won't affect `i`, but only for the exact same reason you can expect that `f3(i.f1().f2()).f4()` won't affect `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, there is no "microstep". Only `step`.

But I often use the `!` statement to execute parts of a line. To use your example above:

```
>>> def foo(i):
...     return 2*i**2 + 3*i + 4
>>>
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.runcall(foo, 5)
-> return 2*i**2 + 3*i + 4
(Pdb) !2*i**2
50
(Pdb) !3*i + 4
19
```

And if there are multiple functions in the line but I only want to step into one of them, I use `debug` to enter a recursive debugger:

```
>>> def foo(i):
...     return fn(i) + fn2(i) * fn3(i)
>>>
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.runcall(foo, 5)
-> return fn(i) + fn2(i) * fn3(i)
(Pdb) debug fn3(i)
ENTERING RECURSIVE DEBUGGER
> <string>(1)<module>()
((Pdb))
# step through fn3 code...
```

More information on `!` and other commands [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands).

Comment: After thinking about this a little, certainly in the case of functions, if you step (s) into a function and return (r), you find yourself on what is returned.  This may be about the best I can hope for.  This doesn't help for built=in functions like chr() and ord().

Comment: Ah, stepping and returning quickly. I use that, too. In general, I feel like I use the debugger so much that I have developed some sequences of commands that are ingrained into the edge of my brain and executed quickly when I need them. Whenever someone watches me do them, they think I'm crazy because they can be very repetitive and fast. And yet, I know exactly what I'm doing. So I guess practicing with the debugger is key.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Well, you can't step into builtin functions, because there's nothing to step into, unless pdb included a C-level debugger like gdb…